# push state object into state array in reactJS application

Tags: reactjs

I have a store file which contains states. I defined user like this:

```
user: store.getState().user || { jobRecord: [] },
```

What I want is to push some job objects into user.jobRecord. The job object is defined like this:

```
job: store.getState().job || { title: '', company: '', start_date: 
'', end_date: '' }
```

So first of all, I set some value into job object and then push it into user.jobRecord.

```
const joined = user && user.jobRecord;
store.setState({
  user: {
  ...user,
  jobRecord: [...joined, job],
  },
});
```

By doing this, I get type error:

> TypeError: joined is not iterable

I try this to set just one record in it:

```
jobRecord: [job],
```

but the result of jobRecord is:

> [object Object]

Thank you a lot for considering my issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, this information is not enough to solve the problem. For example, what does `store.setState` does? Is it the same as `useState`'s setter method? But, this is absolutely true: `joined` is not iterable. So it is not either an array or an object at that time. Try to log it and see if it is `undefined` or something else.

Comment: Yes, joined is undefined. What about the second try? I logged and the one job object set into user.jobRecord. I post it via api call to be stored in database, but it stores [object Object]

Comment: I couldn't understand how you set one `job` but seeing the `jobRecored` as `[object Object]` seems fine to me. Where do you check it? Developer console maybe?

Comment: @devserkan how does it seem fine while it doesn't show the containing of object? I check it by sending get request to my local server.

Comment: But how do you try to see it? It looks an array containing an object. Nevertheless, have you checked @tarzen chugh's answer?

Comment: The array and its object contain looks fine in developer console. I post it through my local api, store it in mongodb collection. But when I fetch it from database, I see it is [object Object] not the fine one I saw in console :( the tarzen's answer didn't work

Comment: After you fetch it how do you inspect it and see as `[object Object]`? By the way, this is another case apart from this problem. After checking @tarzen chugh's answer, did you log `joined` again? Is it still `undefined`?

Comment: would you please check your twitter direct? apologize you in advance, I got you in trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to iterate `undefined` value

`const joined = user && user.jobRecord` assigns undefined value to `joined` variable when `user` or `user.jobRecord` in undefined

To fix it, please use following code instead:

```
const joined = user && user.jobRecord || [];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for falsey value in `store.getState().user` which is actually an object. Therefore it will always be true and `jobRecord` would never be filled and `[...user]` would give error as you are destructuring on empty object.

```
user: store.getState().user || { jobRecord: [] },
```

To avoid this issue use `Object.keys(this.state.user).length` to check if object is empty or not.

Working code below:-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    job: {},
    user: {}
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    let user= Object.keys(this.state.user).length || { jobRecord: [] };

    let job= this.state.job || {
      title: '',
      company: '',
      start_date: '',
      end_date: ''
    };

    const joined = user && user.jobRecord;
    this.setState({
      user: {
      ...user,
      jobRecord: [...joined, job],
      },
    });
  }
  render () {
    console.log('inside user',this.state.user)
    return (
      <div className="App">
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```